# Where do custom Drush hooks go?

Tags: drush

I am attempting to sanitize my database as described in [this Acquia guide](https://docs.acquia.com/articles/scrubbing-drupal-database-environment).

For my site, I need to sanitize all the usernames as well; I would like to sanitize the usernames exactly the same as the e-mail addresses.

The guide suggests using a hook such as this:

```
<?php
/**
* Implementation of hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize().
*/
function modulename_drush_sql_sync_sanitize($source) {
    $query = "UPDATE content_type_profile SET field_primary_email_email = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(field_primary_email_email,'@', 1), '@example.com');";

    $query .= "UPDATE content_type_profile SET field_work_phone_value = SUBSTRING(FLOOR(RAND() * 1000000000000) WHERE uid NOT IN  SELECT uid FROM users_roles WHERE rid=3) AND uid > 0 FROM 1 FOR 12)  WHERE field_work_phone_value IS NOT NULL;";

   drush_sql_register_post_sync_op('my-sanitize-id', dt('Sanitize email addresses and phone numbers'), $query);
}
?>
```

But since this is for Drush, I don't know where to put the hook.  I tried modifying the code and  adding it to an enabled module on my site, but when I ran sql-sanitize, it didn't pick up the hook.

This is what I did.  In MYMODULE/MYMODULE.module, I added the following code:

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_drush_sql_sync_sanitize().
*/
function MYMODULE_drush_sql_sync_sanitize($source) {
    $query = "UPDATE user SET name = CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name,'@', 1), '@example.com');";


   drush_sql_register_post_sync_op('my-sanitize-id', dt('Sanitize user names'), $query);
}
?>
```

Comment: Is your module enabled? If it is, try adding it in a MYMODULE.drush.inc file, that's where custom commands [usually go](http://drush.ws/docs/commands.html) but I'm not sure if the same applies to hooks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the drush code this is the function that looks for the "hooks"

```
drush_command_invoke_all('drush_sql_sync_sanitize', 'default');
```

following the path at the end is calling to:

```
drush_commandfile_list()
```

which is going to look for hooks implementations in the next folders:

- The "/path/to/drush/commands" folder.
- Folders listed in the 'include' option (see example.drushrc.php).
- The system-wide drush commands folder, e.g. /usr/share/drush/commands
- The ".drush" folder in the user's HOME folder.
- /drush and sites/all/drush in current Drupal site.
- Folders belonging to enabled modules in the current Drupal site.

So as @Clive suggested probably MYMODULE.drush.inc and MYMODULE_drush_sql_sync_sanitize should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can run `drush -d status` (or any other command, `-d` for Debug) to see where drush actually looking for the files and what files it's trying to load, e.g.:

```
$ drush -d status
Using the Drush script found at /usr/local/share/drush/drush.launcher using pcntl_exec
Drush preflight prepare loaded autoloader at                         [preflight]
/usr/local/share/drush/vendor/autoload.php [0.01 sec, 2.99 MB]
Starting Drush preflight. [0.01 sec, 2.99 MB]                                                                                                                                              [preflight]
Cache HIT cid: 8.1-dev-commandfiles-0-80c764c89cea212b4c95e9b4349fa821 [0.02 sec, 3.06 MB]                                                                                                     [debug]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.06 sec, 5.67 MB]                                                                                                                [debug]
Scanning into /etc/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.06 sec, 5.67 MB]                                                                                                              [debug]
Scanning into /usr/local/share/drush/includes/.. for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.06 sec, 5.67 MB]                                                                                        [debug]
Scanning into /usr/local/share/drush/includes/.. for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.1 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                       [debug]
Scanning into /home/vagrant/.drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.14 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                                      [debug]
Scanning into /home/vagrant/.drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.14 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                                    [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/../drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.14 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                           [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/../drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.14 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                         [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.14 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                              [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.14 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                            [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/sites/all/drush for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.14 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                    [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/sites/all/drush for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.15 sec, 5.68 MB]                                                                                  [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/sites/default for /.*aliases\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.15 sec, 5.69 MB]                                                                                      [debug]
Scanning into /var/www/sites/default for /self\.alias\.drush(8|)rc\.php$/ [0.15 sec, 5.69 MB]                                                                                    [debug]
Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.61 sec, 7.9 MB]
```

Basically you can copy drush files (such as `drushrc.php`, `*.drushrc.php`, `*.drush.inc`) into any of the following locations:

1. Drupal's `drush`, `../drush` or `sites/all/drush` folder relative to your document root (however `sql-sync` validation could not work here).
2. A `.drush` folder in your `HOME` folder.
3. Anywhere in a folder tree below an active module on your site.
4. `/usr/share/drush/commands` (this is configurable).
5. In an arbitrary folder specified with the `--include` option.